# how to use x[i][j] to index a matrix in C++? Final solution included.

Tags: c++

I have the following C++ code that defines a Vector class and a Matrix class. I'd like to use indexing such as 'm[i][j]' to access the elements in Matrix.

But the compiler raises an error at this line

```
std::cout << data[i][j];
```

in the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
class Vector{
public:
  Vector(int length){
    size = length;
    data = new T[size];
  }
  ~Vector(){
    delete [] data;
  }
  void set_value(T value){
    for (int i = 0; i< size; i++){
      data[i] = value;
    }
  }
  void print(){
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
      std::cout << data[i] << std::endl;
    }
  }

  T operator[](int index){
    return data[index];
  }
private:
  T * data;
  int size;
};

template<class T>
class Matrix{
public:
  Matrix(int height, int width) {
    this -> height = height;
    this -> width = width;
    Vector<T> * * data = new Vector<T> * [height];
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++){
      data[i] = new Vector<T>(width);
    }
  }
  
  ~Matrix(){
    for (int i = 0; i <= width; i++){
      delete [] data[i];
    }
    delete [] data;
  }
void set_value(T value){
    for (int i = 0; i <= height; i++){
      data[i] -> set_value(value);
    }
  }

  void print(){
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++){
      for (int j = 0; j< width; j++){
        std::cout << data[i][j];
      }
      std::cout << std::endl;
    }
  }

  Vector<T> * operator[](int index){
    return data[index];
  }
private:
  Vector<T> * * data;
  int height;
  int width;
};

int main(){
  Vector<float> v = Vector<float>(10);
  v.set_value(1.0);
  std::cout << v[1] << std::endl;

  Matrix<float> m = Matrix<float>(10, 10);
  m.set_value(1.0);
  m.print();
  std::cout << m[5][5] << std::endl;
}
```

I search a bit but got no direct answers. Helps are much appreciated folks. Thanks in advance.

The specific error message is the following:

> cannot bind ‘std::ostream’ lvalue to ‘std::basic_ostream&&’

---

#### I modified the code according to the friendly suggestions below.

## It compiles now, but running it gives 'segmentation fault' after printing '1' in stdout.

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
class Vector{
public:
  Vector(int length){
    size = length;
    data = new T[size];
  }
  ~Vector(){
    delete [] data;
  }
  void set_value(T value){
    for (int i = 0; i< size; i++){
      data[i] = value;
    }
  }
  void print(){
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
      std::cout << data[i] << std::endl;
    }
  }

  T operator[](int index){
    return data[index];
  }
private:
  T * data;
  int size;
};

template<class T>
class Matrix{
public:
  Matrix(int height, int width) {
    this -> height = height;
    this -> width = width;
    Vector<T> * * data = new Vector<T> * [height];
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++){
      data[i] = new Vector<T>(width);
    }
  }
  
  ~Matrix(){
    for (int i = 0; i <= width; i++){
      delete [] data[i];
    }
    delete [] data;
  }
  
  void set_value(T value){
    for (int i = 0; i <= height; i++){
      data[i] -> set_value(value);
    }
  }

  void print(){
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++){
      for (int j = 0; j< width; j++){
    std::cout << (*this)[i][j];
      }
      std::cout << std::endl;
    }
  }

  Vector<T>&  operator[](int index){
    return *(data[index]);
  }
private:
  Vector<T> * * data;
  int height;
  int width;
};

int main(){
  Vector<float> v = Vector<float>(10);
  v.set_value(1.0);
  std::cout << v[1] << std::endl;

  Matrix<float> m = Matrix<float>(10, 10);
  m.set_value(1.0);
  m.print();
  std::cout << m[5][5] << std::endl;
}
```

---

### UPDATES

#### after fixing all the bugs with pointers etc, a solution that seems to work, thanks for all the kind helps!

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
class Vector{
public:
  Vector(int length){
    size = length;
    data = new T[size];
  }
  ~Vector(){
    delete [] data;
  }
  void set_value(T value){
    for (int i = 0; i< size; i++){
      data[i] = value;
    }
  }
  void print(){
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
      std::cout << data[i] << std::endl;
    }
  }

  T operator[](int index){
    return data[index];
  }
private:
  T * data;
  int size;
};

template<class T>
class Matrix{
public:
  Matrix(int height, int width) {
    this -> height = height;
    this -> width = width;
    data = new Vector<T> * [height];
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++){
      data[i] = new Vector<T>(width);
    }
  }
  
  ~Matrix(){
    for (int i = 0; i <= width; i++){
      delete data[i];
    }
    delete [] data;
  }
  
  void set_value(T value){
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++){
      data[i] -> set_value(value);
    }
  }

  void print(){
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++){
      for (int j = 0; j< width; j++){
  std::cout << (*this)[i][j];
      }
      std::cout << std::endl;
    }
  }

  Vector<T>&  operator[](int index){
    return *(data[index]);
  }
private:
  Vector<T> * * data;
  int height;
  int width;
};

int main(){
  Matrix<float> m = Matrix<float>(10, 5);
  m.set_value(1.0);
  m.print();
}
```

Comment: On what line are you geting the error?

Comment: Quick glance: perhaps its because you're returning a pointer to a Vector<T>, you should return a reference (and include a const overload for const-correctness)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  Matrix(int height, int width) {
    this -> height = height;
    this -> width = width;
    Vector<T> * * data = new Vector<T> * [height];
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++){
      data[i] = new Vector<T>(width);
    }
  }
```

should be

```
  Matrix(int height, int width) {
    this -> height = height;
    this -> width = width;
    data = new Vector<T> * [height];
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++){
      data[i] = new Vector<T>(width);
    }
  }
```

Your version declares `data` as a local variable and shadows the class level variable with the same name. It's a common newbie error.

Answer (score 2):

Change `Matrix::operator[](int index)` so that it returns a reference to a `Vector` instead of a pointer.  Otherwise the matrix syntax will not work.

**Edit:**
In this line:

```
Vector<T> * * data = new Vector<T> * [height];
```

You are creating a new local variable `data` that is hiding your member variable `data`.  Change it to:

```
data = new Vector<T> * [height];
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I modified the code accordingly. To my great joy, it compiles now, but gives a segmentation fault. I pasted the modified version above.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your constructor is implemented incorrectly. You do

```
 Vector<T> * * data = new Vector<T> * [height];
```

This will initialize a local variable `data` and store the result of `new[]` in that local pointer. What you need is to store the pointer in the *class member* `data`, not in a local variable. Remove the local variable declaration and work with member `data` instead.

Secondly, there is an error in the destructor of your matrix class. In the destructor, `delete [] data` is correct, but `delete [] data[i]` inside the cycle is completely incorrect. Inside the cycle you should use `delete`, not `delete []`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been resolved (I tested it already). It outputs in stdout

```
11111
11111
11111
11111
11111
11111
11111
11111
11111
11111
```

Seems to be the right thing to do.